# acces current SKU value productAttributeCombiantion nopcommerce

Tags: javascript, c#, nopcommerce

iam trying to acces SKU of current selected combination of attributes,

I found methods that are used to update,show SKU but those are inside JS script, which I cannot acces the data from outside the script,

https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/master/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Views/Product/_ProductAttributes.cshtml#L447

Do you have any idea, how could I get value(number) of current selected product's attributes SKU ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom [trigger](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/master/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Views/Product/_ProductAttributes.cshtml#LL498C54-L498C80) (`$(document).trigger({ type: "product_attributes_changed", changedData: data });`) in that js function. You can define your own function like [this](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/master/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Views/Product/_DeliveryInfo.cshtml#L6).

```
$(document).on("product_attributes_changed", function (data) {
    //do something with 'data'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jaber, I gave up on nopcommerce, and went to other solutions instead